# How to remove duplicate file tracking in Git

Tags: git, github

One of my files is tracked twice after I changed the name of my folder.

Git is now tracking the following two files, which are actually the same file.

> src/Website/scripts/common.js
>
> src/Website/Scripts/common.js

How can I remove the second one from be tracked? This folder doesn't excist anymore, because I renamed it from `Scripts` to `scripts`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
git rm --cached /src/Website/Scripts/common.js
git commit
```

--cached makes git refer to the versioned state, rather than the working tree.

Comment: the `-r` switch is only needed for recursive removal (removing directories). A single file does not require it.